# Transmons and cooper pair box qubits: two islands or a single island and a reservoir

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture, superconducting-quantum-computing

In scientific literature, one typically describes Cooper pair boxes as a small superconducting island coupled to a superconducting reservoir (say, a large ground plane of superconducting metal, or a large piece in any case) via a Josephson junction. This is for example illustrated in panel c below, taken from [here](https://qudev.phys.ethz.ch/node/2182)

[image]

The main innovation of the transmon over the Cooper pair box was (if I am not mistaken) to shunt the island with a large capacitance, so as to decrease the sensitivity to charge. One can do this while maintaining the geometry of having an island and a large reservoir; see for example figure 1a of [Anharmonicity of a Gatemon Qubit with a Few-Mode Josephson Junction by Kringhoj et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05643), where their Josephson junction (in this case an SNS junction made from a nanowire) shunts a T shaped island to the ground plane, the reservoir in this case. The large capacitance here is to ground. I apologise for using an exotic transmon here, I couldn't find a nice picture of a standard one; [Studying Light-Harvesting Models with Superconducting Circuits by Potocnik et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07466) has grounded $\require{\mhchem}\ce{AlOx}$ transmons in figure 1b, but the level of zoom is a little low.

But something that I often see in modern transmon designs is that it is not a shunted island coupled to a reservoir; it is instead two coupled islands; take this figure from [here](http://blog.qutech.nl/index.php/2017/08/13/how-to-make-artificial-atoms-out-of-electrical-circuits-part-ii-circuit-quantum-electrodynamics-and-the-transmon/). The capacitance here is between the two plates themselves.

[image]

Optically and intuitively, I would say that this is a rather different device; instead of having a small, isolated (up to Josephson coupling) island coupled to a large reservoir with a very large number of charges (which might even be grounded), one now has two such small, isolated islands with a small number of charges, galvanically isolated from the rest of the circuit. Moreover, the capacitance is now not to ground, but between the islands.

Now, I know that the Hamiltonian of these systems does not care about this difference; what matters is the number of Cooper pairs which have tunnelled *across* the junction, not the actual number of charges *on* the island(s). What my question is, is how in practice these devices *do* differ; why would one make their transmon in one way or the other? What constraints/considerations/findings have led modern designs to favour the two island version (if this is even true)? Do they have a better life and or coherence times, and if so, why? I've been trying to find literature that talks about the distinction between the two, but I have been unsuccessful.

---

**Note:** This has been [cross posted on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425302/transmons-and-cooper-pair-box-qubits-two-islands-or-a-single-island-and-a-reser).

Comment: [cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425302/58382)

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of the transmon design is the additional loop you gain from what you called two-island-design. The yellow flux bias line changes the [Josephson energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect#Josephson_energy), thus the resonance of the qubit. You can imagine this as changing the (Josephson) inductance of the SQUID loop being a non-linear LC-resonator. This helps for example in two-qubit gate implementations that rely on identical qubit frequencies. But it comes at the cost of higher sensitivity to flux noise. More details you can find in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02253).

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer! Sadly this is not exactly the answer I was looking for, as it concerns the advantages of a DC SQUID over an AC SQUID (or a fixed-frequency transmon vs a flux biased transmon). Instead I am trying to find out what the difference is between a transmon (or CPB) that connects a large reservoir (such as the ground plane) to a single island, or that connects two islands. One can make a DC SQUID in both geometries (see for example the paper by Potocnik I quote, that has flux biasing and junctions between a single island and ground)